# SSH to a remote linux machine shows -bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied warning

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, permissions

The following are the steps I performed:

1. SSH to a CentOS 6.x machine that is in the local network with command

> ssh root@192.168.0.1

2. Enter the root user password
3. I was able to successfully login to the machine, but I only get the bash terminal instead of the root user terminal.

> Last login: Wed Apr 25 18:04:32 2018 from 192.168.0.27
>
> -bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
>
> -bash-4.1#

I am trying to understand what is the problem here.

Additional info:

1. I am able to login to any other machine in the local network without having this issue.
2. Also, from the bash terminal, I am able to switch to the super user account with "su" command.

Few command executed on the remote machine which I'm trying to login and its output.

```
-bash-4.1# whoami
root


-bash-4.1# stat /root/.bashrc
File: `/root/.bashrc'
Size: 221           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 32510289    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/      root)
Access: 2018-04-26 10:09:04.206129757 +0530
Modify: 2018-04-25 18:04:59.354903860 +0530
Change: 2018-04-25 18:04:59.389903855 +0530


-bash-4.1# file /root/.bashrc
/root/.bashrc: ASCII text


-bash-4.1# lsattr /root/.bashrc
-------------e- /root/.bashrc
```

Bashrc content:

```
#/bin/bash -x

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
export PATH="/opt/postgres/postgresql:$PATH"
```

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: You might need to execute the ssh comand as root too. `su ; ssh root@192.168.0.1` or `sudo ssh root@192.168.0.1`. You should also  consider using privates key instead of password authentication (for your own security): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Comment: Please try these commands that can help identify the issue (but won't fix the issue) and let us know what the outputs are: `whoami`, `stat /root/.bashrc`, `file /root/.bashrc`, `lsattr /root/.bashrc`

Comment: @Deltik I  have added the output of the requested commands to the question...

Comment: @kenorb I dont get permission denied error on executing the debug command...

Comment: Can you add/modify the first line of that file to `#/bin/bash -x`, to apply tracing, and re-produce the issue again?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan Sorry, my mistake, it should be [`#!/bin/bash -x`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (note the `!`).

Comment: @kenorb Well, no changes still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76595/discussion-between-bala-krishnan-and-kenorb).

Comment: It looks like something is trying to execute /root/.bashrc but you get an error because the file is missing +x permission. (But I don't know why this is happening.)

Answer (score 0):

> -bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied

- Check the permissions of `.bashrc` file (which you did).
- Check the permissions of all files which you're including (such as `/etc/bashrc`).
- Check the permissions of all files which your global `/etc/bashrc` is including.
- Check the permissions of your `/etc` folder (see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154888/21471)). For example:

  ```
    chmod 0755 /etc # run as root
  ```
- Consider adding `-vvv` when running `ssh` for more detailed output.

---

#### Tracing

To further debug the problem, you can enable tracing (`xtrace`) in your shell. Here are 3 methods:

1. Using [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

   Add the following line as the first one to your script:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash -x
   ```
2. Add `set -x` line at the very start of your startup script file.
3. Run `bash` with `-x` along with `ssh` command, e.g.

   ```
    \ssh -vvv root@192.168.0.1 -t bash -x
   ```

After that, try to reproduce the issue again, then you should find the problematic line.

Comment: No, this isn't working... the permissions of .bashrc, /etc/bashrc are all correct and doesn't have any issues... the trace command that I added in the header is not working.. this is not a solution...

Comment: If your shebang  doesn't work for some reason, add `set -x` on the second line. This should work.